# Why is one of my base class constructors deleted? (C++11)

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, constructor

I wrote a simple C++11 program in which I create a class that's derived from `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class my_vec : public vector<T> {
public:
  using vector<T>::vector;
};

int main() {
  my_vec<int> v0;
  my_vec<int> v1 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  my_vec<int> v2 ( 42 );
  my_vec<int> v3 ( v1 );
  my_vec<int> v4 ( v1.begin()+1, v1.end()-1 );
  return 0;
}
```

Granted, `my_vec` doesn't do anything over and above `std::vector`, but that's because I removed all my extra functionality in narrowing down my error. This program compiles fine on g++ 4.8.1 on Linux, but when using clang 500.2.79 on OS X, it gives me the following error:

```
myvec.cpp:16:15: error: call to deleted constructor of 'my_vec<int>'
  my_vec<int> v4 ( v1.begin()+1, v1.end()-1 );
              ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
myvec.cpp:8:20: note: function has been explicitly marked deleted here
  using vector<T>::vector;
                   ^
1 error generated.
```

Why does clang insist that `std::vector`'s range constructor has been deleted? All the other constructors seem to have been inherited just fine.

Comment: [Compiles for me](http://ideone.com/wTNQrN)

Comment: My `clang` does the same, and i'm pretty sure its because they are template-constructors. I'd have to dive into docs to know whether or not that is a bug or standard-compliant.

Comment: Keep in mind that `std::vector` does not have a virtual destructor and is not intended to be used as a base class.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but can only advise you against inheriting from stl containers. First of all, their destructors are not virtual. Also, you can assign an std::vector from a my_vec instance without any warning whatsoever. This can be a problem if my_vec was supposed to do somtething special to destroy its elements.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: "does not have a virtual destructor" is correct. "is not indended to be used as a base class" is a **frivolous nonsense claim**. as an example of a stndard library class that does not have a virtual destructor, yet is clearly designed to be derived from, `std::stack` has a protected member (which is only meaningful for a derived class) and no virtual destructor. just repeating, your claim is utter nonsense. it's food for thought that currently 3 SO readers have upvoted your comment; it says something about a general incompetence of SO readers.

Comment: it fails with g++4.7 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9032cdaf8233cf8c, but is ok with 4.8

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But he is not saying that it is not intended as a base class *because* there is no virtual destructor.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan: if you are an alternate nick for the person whose thoughts you have insights about, then I can accept that your claim that also Captain Obvious' first claim, is utter nonsense (in context). However, I suspect that you're someone else, who just believes in telepathy. I.e., also your comment is balderdash, and very obviously so.

Comment: @marcin_j inheriting ctors are not implemented in g++4.7, they've been introduced in g++4.8 See http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: yeah, and in clang they are available since 3.3 (http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OS X compiler is based on llvm clang-3.3 (checked on google), from this site http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html it looks like inheriting constructors should be available from version 3.3, but it looks like its implementation is buggy in this version.

I checked on ubuntu with clang 3.5 and your sample code compiles fine.

Answer (score 3):

It probably has something to do with the fact that the range constructor is not a regular method, but a template method.

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, and his code is valid and compiles in newer compilers.

Comment: I'm not saying it should, but it's one of the most significant differences between this constructor and the others.